# Convert markdown to mdast tree with gfm extention don't work (Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'inTable'))

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I try to convert an .md file to a mdast tree(JSON) using a gfm extention in Next.js 13 and I got an Typescript in VSC and Next.js "Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'inTable')" error in the browser.

The code is the next one:

```
"use server"
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import matter from 'gray-matter';
import { fromMarkdown } from "mdast-util-from-markdown"
import { gfm } from 'micromark-extension-gfm'
import { gfmFromMarkdown, gfmToMarkdown } from 'mdast-util-gfm'

const postsDirectory = path.join(process.cwd(), 'blogposts');

export async function getPostDataToEdit (id: string) {
  const fullPath = path.join(postsDirectory, `${id}.md`);
  const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(fullPath, 'utf8');
  const matterResult = matter(fileContents);

  const tree = fromMarkdown(fileContents,'utf8' , {
    extensions: [gfm()],
    mdastExtensions: [ gfmFromMarkdown() ]
  })

  const blogPost: BlogPost & {  body: any } = {
    id,
    title: matterResult.data.title,
    date: matterResult.data.date,
    published: matterResult.data.published ? "Published" : "Draft",
    body: tree,
  }

  return blogPost;
}
```

The typescript error is:

[typescript error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIQ0g.jpg)

The Next.js error is:

[Next.js error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cI7Do.jpg)

Please, can you help me?

Thanks!!

I read the documentation of mdast-util-from-markdown and mdast-util-gfm and couldn't solve this. If I remove the extention section from the function "fromMarkdown" works just fine but without idenifying the gfm markdown on the file, just only common markdown.

The code without extention section:

```
"use server"
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import matter from 'gray-matter';
import { fromMarkdown } from "mdast-util-from-markdown"
import { gfm } from 'micromark-extension-gfm'
import { gfmFromMarkdown, gfmToMarkdown } from 'mdast-util-gfm'

const postsDirectory = path.join(process.cwd(), 'blogposts');

export async function getPostDataToEdit (id: string) {
  const fullPath = path.join(postsDirectory, `${id}.md`);
  const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(fullPath, 'utf8');
  const matterResult = matter(fileContents);

  const tree = fromMarkdown(fileContents,'utf8' , {
  })

  const blogPost: BlogPost & {  body: any } = {
    id,
    title: matterResult.data.title,
    date: matterResult.data.date,
    published: matterResult.data.published ? "Published" : "Draft",
    body: tree,
  }

  return blogPost;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain what you're doing wrong, but try downgrading to the previous major version of `gfm`. I use version `3.0.1` of remark-gfm and it works in my Next app.

Comment: It seems the official recommendation is to use the previous version until some dependencies are updated. You can read more here. https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown/issues/763